# bookdown and MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, bookdown

I notice in the [`bookdown` book this information](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/software-information-and-conventions.html):

> ... your book does not have to be related to the R language at
> all. It can use other computing languages (C++, SQL, Python, and so
> on; see Appendix B)...

I am interested to know: Can `bookdown` be coerced to work with `MATLAB`? If so, has anyone done so (I can't find evidence)?

(I have not been a `MATLAB` user for over 15 years, but I have interested colleagues.)

P.

Comment: Did you read Appendix B? It links to [this page](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/language-engines.html) that lists all supported languages. MATLAB is not among them. But you might be able to write a MATLAB engine for knitr yourself? I have no idea what would be required, but it is fairly straightforward to communicate with a MATLAB session...

Comment: Right, there isn't a MATLAB engine in knitr. Someone tried to contribute an Octave engine a number of years ago: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/pull/866 Not sure if that supports MATLAB (probably not). If anyone wants to contribute a MATLAB engine to knitr and can promise to maintain it, I'll be happy to include it in knitr.

Comment: Thanks Cris. Yes, read Appendix B, but did not realise that link would list all the available engines. Given the text, I thought it would show *non-simple* examples.

Anyway, thanks for the information.